# How to show all products in nopCommerce?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I would like to show all products without creating any new category and mapping to it.

Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Making a new category sounds like a sensible approach. Why doesn't it suit you?

Comment: Could you please post your code and mark it as accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

It's true; in order for a product to be displayed in nopCommerce, it must be assigned to a category. Your best bet is to create a top-level umbrella category, like "All Products", and add all of your products to that umbrella category.

Comment: Hi Carole, I have managed it by getting all categories and making LINQ to it and got all the products. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know their must be a category associated with product.

Comment: Hi Manoj, I have managed it by getting all categories and making LINQ to it and got all the products. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin, map a route to it (for example map to 'allproducts' route), and create your own Controllers, Actions and Views within the plugin. Then insert in the main menu a link to the route by mean of

```
@Html.RouteLink(routeName, null) //or similar overloads
```

The plugin creation part is too huge to be described here. http://www.nopcommerce.com/documentation.aspx is a good start.

PS:/ Regarding routing, each plugin can implement a route registrar by implementing the "IRouteProvider" interface.

:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by modifying the code. I have done it before. It is actually quite simple.

Modify the Category action of the Catalogue controller to receive a nullable CategoryId:

```
public ActionResult Category(int? categoryId, CatalogPagingFilteringModel command){
```

modify the action to not break because of this nullable paramters.

The most important part to modify is where you build the list of category Ids to filter:

```
var categoryIds = new List<int>();
if (category != null)
   {
       categoryIds.Add(category.Id);
   }
if (_catalogSettings.ShowProductsFromSubcategories)
   {
       //include subcategories
       categoryIds.AddRange(GetChildCategoryIds(category.Id));
   }
```

The mothod _productService.SearchProducts will receive an empty list of category Ids and will not filter any products.

Comment: Hi Carlos, I have managed it by getting all categories and making LINQ to it and got all the products. But though your given solution looks more promising, let me try this one and I will get back to you on this. Thanks for your help.